# PDO driver not working in Apache and PHP Docker container

Tags: php, docker, apache, pdo, containers

I am trying to get the PDO driver working on my containers. I have a seperate Apache2 and PHP container. I get the "no value" message on my phpinfo page.

I copy a php.ini file into the Apache2 container which uncomments the PDO extension lines.

What am I doing wrong here?

I have created a custom dockerfile which installs Apache2:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apache2 php php-fpm

CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

COPY apache-vhost.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/apache-vhost.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini

RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/apache-vhost.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

PHP dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
```

Docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  php:
    build:
      context: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./page:/var/www/html/

  apache2:
    build:
      context: ./Apache2
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    volumes:
      - ./page:/var/www/html/
```

Comment: php and php-fpm may be different.

Comment: The case for running separate Apache and FPM containers means you don't install any form of PHP with Apache. You configure the FPM container to listen on a port and configure Apache to forward FastCGI requests to that. You _can_ install PHP in the Apache container and ditch FPM, but at that point just use the apache tag from the PHP image repo.